# How to store a cookie with php

Tags: php

How can a save a cookie using php for every visitor on my site? My website also has a unique ID generator. I want to know how to make the id stay the same using cookies

Comment: `My website also has a unique ID generator. I want to know how to make the id stay the same using cookies` Just curious why not using built-in PHP session handler?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function to store a cookie.

**Example Code**

```
//Check if cookie exists
if (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
    //Get UID from cookie
    $uid = $_COOKIE['uid'];
} else {
    //Generate UID
    $uid = uniqid();
    //Store in cookie
    setcookie('uid',$uid);
}
```

Comment: I have been looking into this as well. The problem with uniqid is that it is possible that you will have a duplicate, so it is not safe if you want to use it as an identifier

Answer (score -1):

You could check [W3Schools' PHP guide](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp), it has a lot of useful code snippets to do with cookies.
 Depending what you are doing, you may also want to check out Sessions.

Comment: -1: http://w3fools.com/  Referring to the PHP Manual would be a better reference as there are tons of examples on the manual and the manual is generally up to date and correct.

Comment: My apologies, retrospectively thinking i'd have too agree. I was just speaking from experience that I used w3schools when dealing with cookies.

Comment: Gotcha :) If you edit it, I will remove the downvote (just add a period or something.)