# $_SESSION v. $_COOKIE

Tags: php, session, cookies

I learned about `$_SESSION` about several weeks ago when creating a login page. I can successfully login and use it with variables. Currently I am trying to understand `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`. Please correct me if I am wrong, I can use `$_SESSION` when logging in and moving around pages. With `$_COOKIE`, it is used to remember when I last visit and preferences.

Another thing involving cookies is that when websites use advertisements (for example: Google AdSense), they use the cookies to track when visitor click on a advertisement, right?

I can use both (`$_SESSION` & `$_COOKIE`)? I read somewhere that you can store the `session_id` as value for the cookie.

Also, I read about security which let to me finding this: [What do I need to store in the php session when user logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221447/what-do-i-need-to-store-in-the-php-session-when-user-logged-in/1225668#1225668). Is using `session_regenerate_id` good for when a user comes back to the site?

And this: [How to store a cookie with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742649/how-to-store-a-cookie-with-php) involving `uniqid`.

For those wanting to know about the login, I use email and password. That way the user can be able to change their username.

I look forward to learning more about these two from anybody who would like to share their knowledge about it. If I asked too many question, you can just answer the one that you have more experience with.

If you need more information, just ask since I might have forgotten to include something.

Thank You.

---

Found this: [What risks should I be aware of before allowing advertisements being placed on my website?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7840/what-risks-should-i-be-aware-of-before-allowing-advertisements-being-placed-on-m)

Comment: "Is using session_regenerate_id good for when a user comes back to the site?" --- for what reason?

Comment: Session is a server-side storage, cookie - client-side. That's the major difference

Comment: @zerkms session_regenerate_id is something I read about and made me curious.

Comment: so? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: After you authenticate a user, you should regenerate the session id.  People can hijack the session if they know the session id and then get access to information they shouldn't have.  By regenerating after authentication, you are largely taking that away.  Also, just as standard practice if you don't know the full implications, don't put the session id in the URL.

Comment: @phpmeh: "After you authenticate a user, you should regenerate the session id" -- there is no reason for that. "People can hijack the session if they know the session id" --- if they could get the session id - then regeneration doesn't add anything

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14093/why-is-passing-the-session-id-as-url-parameter-insecure

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41/good-session-practices

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/how-to-hijack-a-session

Comment: @phpmeh: it doesn't explain anything. You can regenerate session_id even on each request. And it wouldn't make the application bullet-proof protected

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In simple terms, `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` are different. 
Both are php globals but cookies are used without a language limitation. 
`$_SESSION` is all about storing the data in the server while storing the session ID as a cookie. `$_COOKIE` is the cookies that *browser sends* to the server. This is the major difference. Sessions don't work if the client browser has cookies disabled.

**- Security -**

If you checked request headers that your browser sends, you will notice that each request has cookie information in it. They can be tracked by snipping your network communication. 
Anyone with a better tools can edit cookie data.
**never use cookies to store passwords!**
If you use sessions, passwords are in the server and only the session id cookie will stored be in the client, *reducing* the security problem. Chuck Norris still can hijack a session.

**- Performance -**

If you store 5 cookies in the browser with 200 bytes in it, that cost ~1 KB of data on *each and every* request no matter if it's a jpg file or a page that actually needs the cookie information. So this directly affects how fast your site can perform to the end user.

if you use sessions, server has this 1 KB data while the client sends the session ID in each page request. 
You can be clever by shifting static files to another cookie-less domain.

**- Lifetime -**

Sessions gets cleared on timely basis. So if you want to save something for a long time, use cookies instead. "remember me" functionality of most sites works this way (still, it doesn't store the password. Just the session information - not to confuse with session ID).

Bottom line, 
sessions and cookies are different types. session is relatively secure and server side storage. gets cleared often. Cookies can have a larger lifespan but it affects performance (not CPU/RAM -- load times) unless you don't keep that in mind. 
It's extremely strange if there is a reason to store 1 KB as cookies though.

Never trust user input that comes through `$_GET/POST`. Do the same care for `$_COOKIE` as well.
And there is session hijacking. Someone can guess someone else's session ID although it's nearly impossible to do. So use some validation at the server side first.

Comment: So is the cookie that has the session id stored in it, a cookie I can see? Like when I use IE, I can find the folder with the cookies from different sites inside. And if Chuck Norris hijacks a session, Bruce Lee would be my security.

Comment: yes, the session ID is stored in a cookie. that's why sessions doesn't work when cookies are disabled.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So when using cookies, I use the session_id as the value?

Comment: let php do that for you. 
$_COOKIE['popup'] can contain "popup" cookie's value. Likewise, $_SESSION['form_key'] can contain the form_key value from server's session storage with the session ID submitted from the client.

Comment: Alright. So if I want remember me feature, I should just have the value as the email, right? If I have advertisements, it will read the cookie made from php's session.